# Trying to fetch Playlists with thumbnail's from YouTube in node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to fetch playlists from youtube. I am only getting ID, title, and Desc for the playlist.
This is the code I am using. Let me know what I can do to get thumbnails as well.

Thanks!

```
const youtubeVideoParams = `key=${apiKey}&channelId=UCEAH4aJ0QadOFn7yPEfWEHw&part=id,snippet&order=date&maxResults=20`;
app.get('/playlists', cacheMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  fetch(`${googleApiUrl}playlists?${youtubeVideoParams}`).then(response => {
    return response.json();
  }).then(response => {
    const playlists = response.items.map(({
      id,
      snippet
    }) => ({
      id: id,
      title: snippet.title,
      desc: snippet.description,
      thumbnails: snippet.thumbnails,
    })).reverse();
```

Comment: You have a Typo:  thumbnil: snippet.thumbnil,   is not the same as  thumbnails: snippet.thumbnails,

Comment: Thanks, Fixed it but still didn't get the thumbnail.

Comment: The try me says the response is there [try me](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2Cid%22%5D%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCEAH4aJ0QadOFn7yPEfWEHw%22%7D)

Comment: IF you fixed your code with the typo can you edit your question and include the fixed code.   What's the actual output you are getting?

Comment: Getting this: 
    ```{
        "id": "PLNehmw4Mrl1PDW71ReSZVFi1wH_Qcuh7a",
        "title": "HackerRank Solutions in Python",
        "desc": "Some Solutions to HackerRank problems."
    }
```

Comment: are you only using an API Key or are you authorizing a user?

Comment: No, Just using the API key. This is new for me so please ignore if I am doing any dumb mistakes